# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in Django

Tags: python, django

I have encountered a very strange problem.

I'm working with django, I create a directory on server, and try to save pickle file into it, this way:

```
with open(path, 'wb') as output: 
  pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

And get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I tried to give all permissions to this directory, this way:

```
os.chmod(save_full_path, stat.S_IWOTH | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IWGRP)
```

but this didn't help.

Although directory seems to have all permissions(0o777), I still get this error.

By the way, I have no problems with saving uploaded files to this directory.

I'm very new to django, I would really appreciate if someone explained me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you verify the directory's permission from a terminal?

Comment: What is in your 'path' variable? I had this error when in my 'path' was only the directory, not the file extention.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like i have figured out this myself.
Found this question, and did excactly what is written there.

[Permission denied when trying to write to file from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042445/permission-denied-when-trying-to-write-to-file-from-a-view)

But I still don't know what was the problem in my case :(